# Debug angular inside docker container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, webstorm

I have a simple angular application that lives inside a simple docker container.
I am trying to attach a debugger using WebStorm but currently having no joy. It doesn't help that I don't have much JS/Angular experience

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
ENV APP_DIR=/usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
EXPOSE 4200
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  angular-poke-front-end:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ../:/usr/src/app
    entrypoint: [ "npm", "start" ]
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: "development"
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "debug": "",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
...
```

I think I need to have a debug script in my `package.json` file but I wouldn't know how to configure it, then from other resources I've read I might need to pass a debug flag?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about the [subject](https://medium.com/@gparlakov/debugging-angular-framework-running-inside-docker-container-using-vs-code-79a04d814d82)
Otherwise, you are also able to debug your code from the browser by using the chrome dev tools for example

Comment: That article is for debugging the Angular Framework itself inside a docker container. I believe @LazyOne wants to debug his application.